# Rails Spree Cannot transition from payment to complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment, spree, state-machine

I am integrating a custom pay method into my rails app. But I cannot do that my order goes from payment stat to completed state. I am ensure that the payment registered at the order is at completed state, so I cannot figure out why the state machine are telling me "No payment found"

Here's my code.

```
  def perform_payment payment_id, state
    Rails.logger.info("PERFORM PAYMENT => payment_id: #{payment_id}, state: #{state}")
    payment = Spree::Payment.find payment_id
    return unless payment
    order = payment.order
    
    begin
      if state == "accepted"
        payment.started_processing!
        payment.capture!
        Rails.logger.info("PERFORM PAYMENT => order_id:#{order.id}, current_order_state: #{order.state}")
        Rails.logger.info("PERFORM PAYMENT => order_payments:#{order.payments.size}")
        order.next! unless order.state == "completed"
      elsif state == "rejected"
        payment.started_processing!
        payment.failure!
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      Rails.logger.error("Error al procesar pago orden #{order.number}: E -> #{e.message}")
      return false
    end
  end
```

Here's the error that I'm getting

StateMachines::InvalidTransition (Cannot transition state via :next from :payment (Reason(s): No payment found))

Comment: you're processing the payment yourself and then calling `order.next!` which tries to process order payments again and there are no unprocessed payments left. https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v4.4.0/core/app/models/spree/order/payments.rb#L48

Comment: @Alex So... you say that if I deleted the  "payment.started_processing!" and the "payment.capture!" it will work?

Comment: at least the payment should be processed automatically. i don't know how `perform_payment` hooks into the checkout flow. make sure you don't call methods twice that are part of the checkout and state transitions.

Comment: thanks, I will review it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, It was @Alex mentions. It's only neccesary the .netx! on the order. To do that. you need to ensure that you have a payment in "completed" state.